# Rails 3 relationship definition problem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails 3, i'm creating a web app that use active admin, i get a problem with him, and asked for help inside github plugin, someone told me maybe a relationship definitions.

I really dont know what is that, i have nested elements and in active admin i want to make nested element independent.

but now, im totally lost. what i missed? thanks.
here is my model definition

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :getsubdomain

has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :thumb => '150x150>', :medium => '250x250>', :normal => '350x350>'}

has_many :buildings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :buildings

end


Building model
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :companies  

end
```

in my db, i have colum company_id in buildings table.

Here the error message i get..

```
NameError in Admin/buildings#index
Showing /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/active_admin-c3a1ffa98072/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

uninitialized constant Building::Companies

Rails.root: /Users/username/Sites/myapps

Request

Parameters:

{"order"=>"id_desc"}


Response

Headers:

None
```

thanks for your help

Comment: oups sorry im new here hehe i try to replay.

Comment: i'm unable to format, ok, here is what i got for error..  NameError in Admin/buildings#index

Showing /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/active_admin-c3a1ffa98072/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

uninitialized constant Building::Companies

Comment: Please edit the question to include that, it's important information.

Comment: ok, sorry i edited my question. thanks

Comment: could you add your db schema to the question?

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` expects a singular name. Try

```
belongs_to :company
```

Comment: i tried and got this error : ArgumentError

No association found for name `buildings'. Has it been defined yet? when i edit both building.rb and company.rb models

Comment: Check that `has_many :buildings` is before `accepts_nested_attributes_for :buildings`

Comment: Can you comment out the `accepts...` line and see if there is any problem?

Comment: No clue here. Can you update your question with this data and add your last db/schema.rb?